# How to disable `new-cap` of eslint for external types from .d.ts?

Tags: typescript, eslint

Suppose I imported an external library, thus I couldn't alter the code of the library, exposed some funtions which didn't match the `new-cap` rule such as:

```js
// index.d.ts
export FooClass {
    public static export BadFunction();
}
```

And when I tried to use this function in my own code I would get a eslint error such as:

```js
// mycode.ts
function () {
    // ESLint: A function with a name starting with an uppercase letter should only be used as a constructor.(new-cap)
    FooClass.BadFunction();
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Even though I could use `// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap` to disable this error but it is very annoying because I have to add this comment to everywhere that used these external functions.

How can I make eslint to ignore the `new-cap` error for the functions from external .d.ts files?

Comment: If you use typescript you should disable the rule completely, as Typescript won't allow you to call a class anyway

Comment: What's your preset? Are you sure you do not use JS preset instead of TS preset in a TS project?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to disable the new-cap rule at the global configuration level (meaning it won't apply to any file in your project), you can update your ESLint configuration file (.eslintrc.js, .eslintrc.json, or equivalent).

Here's how you can do it:

1 .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
 rules: {
  'new-cap': 'off'
 }
};
```

2 .eslintrc.json:

```
{
  "rules": {
   "new-cap": "off"
  }
}
```

By setting the rule to '**off**', you're effectively disabling the new-cap rule for all files in your project.